# How to keep form items selected after post request.Using onchange

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, onchange, dropdown

I have a problem when submit form value from the second select don't show. Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong because in new in this (maybe is because i use onchange event). Thanks in advance.

index.php

```
<?php 
include("includes/conn.php");

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM opstina";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        $opstineArr = array();
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $opstineArr[] = $row;
        }
    }

    if(isset($_POST["addNesto"])){

        $opstine = $_POST["opstine"];
        $ime = $_POST["ime"];

        if(isset($opstine)){
            if(empty($opstine)){
                $error["opstine"] = "izaberite opstinu";
            }
        }


        $naselja = $_POST["naselja"];
        if(isset($naselja)){
            if(empty($naselja)){
                $error["naselja"] = "izaberite naselje";
            }
        }


        if(isset($ime)){
            if(empty($ime)){
                $error["ime"] = "izaberite ime";
            }
        }

        if(count($error) == 0){
            echo 2222;
        }

    }


    include("includes/header.php");

?>

<form action="" method="POST">
    <select name="opstine" class="form-control" id="select_id" onchange="getNaselja(this.value)">
        <option>..Izaberite Opstinu..</option>
        <?php foreach($opstineArr as $key => $opstina): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $opstina['OpstinaID']; ?>" <?php if(isset($opstine) && $opstine==$opstina['OpstinaID']) echo "selected"; ?> ><?php echo $opstina['NazivOpstine']; ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
    <?php if(isset($error["opstine"])) echo $error["opstine"]; ?>

    <p>
        <select name='naselja' id='naseljeLista' class='form-control' style='margin-top:10px;'>
        </select>
        <span><?php if(isset($error["naselja"])) echo $error["naselja"]; ?></span>
    </p><br>

    <input type="text" name="ime" value="<?php if(isset($ime)) echo $ime; ?>" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"><?php if(isset($error["ime"])) echo $error["ime"]; ?><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="addNesto" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">
</form>
<?php include("includes/footer.php"); ?>
```

getNaselja.php

```
global $conn;
include("includes/conn.php");

    if(!empty($_POST["opstina_id"])){

        $opstinaID = $_POST["opstina_id"];

        $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM naselje WHERE OpstinaID=".$opstinaID;
        $result1 = $conn->query($sql1);
        if($result1->num_rows > 0){
            $naseljaArr = array();
            while ($one = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
                $naseljaArr[] = $one;
            }
        }

        echo "<option value=''>---Izaberite naselje---</option>";
        foreach ($naseljaArr as $key => $value) {
            if(isset($_POST["naselja"]) && $value["NaseljeID"]==$_POST["naselja"]){
                echo "<option value='".$value['NaseljeID']."' selected='selected' style='display:block;'>".$value['NazivNaselja']."</option>";
            }else{
                echo "<option value='".$value['NaseljeID']."'>".$value['NazivNaselja']."</option>";
            }
        }

    }
```

footer.php

```
<script>

        function getNaselja(val){

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'getNaselja.php',
                data: 'opstina_id='+val,
                success: function(data){
                    $('#naseljeLista').html(data);
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });

        }


    </script>
```

[example of form after submit on index.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPhXg.png)

When I choose from first select my data on the console looks like:

```
<option value=''>---Izaberite naselje---</option>
<option value='4610'>Beška</option>
<option value='4611'>Inđija</option>
<option value='4612'>Jarkovci</option>
<option value='4613'>Krčedin</option>
<option value='4614'>Ljukovo</option>
<option value='4615'>Maradik</option>
<option value='4616'>Novi Karlovci</option>
<option value='4617'>Novi Slankamen</option>
<option value='4618'>Slankamenački Vinogradi</option>
<option value='4619'>Stari Slankamen</option>
<option value='4620'>Čortanovci</option>
```

Comment: what does "data" look like? Is it valid HTML? You're replacing all the options, so if there's nothing there, or it's invalid markup, then your select will be blank. The other possibility is that the ajax call is not working - have you checked your console and/or network tab in the browser's Developer Tools to see if there any errors or unexpected results?

Comment: When i choose from first select my data on console look like: <option value=''>---Izaberite naselje---</option><option value='4610'>Beška</option><option value='4611'>Inđija</option><option value='4612'>Jarkovci</option><option value='4613'>Krčedin</option><option value='4614'>Ljukovo</option><option value='4615'>Maradik</option><option value='4616'>Novi Karlovci</option><option value='4617'>Novi Slankamen</option><option value='4618'>Slankamenački Vinogradi</option><option value='4619'>Stari Slankamen</option><option value='4620'>Čortanovci</option>

Comment: I've added that to the question - code in comments is generally very difficult to read. But it does look like valid HTML. If you open the 2nd select are the options there? Maybe it's just not choosing a default value?

Comment: Sorry, i too fast press enter and posted now. HTML looks ok and in console/ network/ headers i have no errors if you mean on that. My english in not so good. Yes, when i open second select, option are there depending on what is selected in first select.

Comment: if you are using ajax to post the data the page should not reload. So what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: I've just realised you're talking about the problem after you've submitted the form. Of course it won't show - the data is only added via ajax. It doesn't persist after a postback, you have to re-create it yourself. Either call the ajax when the page loads, or do something server-side that calls the same code as getNaselja.php does, but only if `opstine` is set.

Comment: I tried to put in footer $(document).ready(function() {}; to circle function getNaselja() and then is not appear second select when i click on first. I must learn more to understand what I don't understand :)